# Can i use .outerWidth() with .css() to move it to the right

Tags: jquery, css, width

**Edited to make question more concise.**

Can i use the outerWidth() value within the .css() method to offset the position of the "#item" by two times it's width.

For example:

```
$("#item").css("left", - (2 x outerwidth(this)));
```

---

The accepted answer, refers heavily to the original (more convoluted and broad) question I asked encompassing a wider set of functions I was developing.

```
elem.css('left', $(window).width()+'px');
```

This moved the element suitably, without relying on the outerWidth() value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var elem = $("#item");

// 1. animate to left
elem.animate({'left': -(2 * elem.outerWidth())+'px'}, function() { 

    // 2. move to outside right border
    elem.css('left', $(window).width()+'px'); 

    // 3. animate to starting position 
    elem.animate({'left': '0px'});
});
```

Comment: As i have 1 sorted, Steps 2 and 3 answered this perfectly.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#item").css("left", - (2 * $('#item').outerWidth()));
```

`outerWidth()` is a jQuery method and for using that you should at first create a jQuery object (by selecting an element). please note that in JavaScript for multiplication you should use `*` operator not `x`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation of the outerWidth(). The integer provided would want +"px"

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in a total padding-left of 25px.

From that, I think what you want is:

```
$("#item").css("left", "-=" + (2 x outerwidth(this)));
```

Note: I'm assuming `outerwidth` is a valid function (likely that you've written yourself) in the above line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
$("#item").css("left", function(i, oldLeft){
    return -2*$(this).outerWidth();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#item").css("left", - (2 * $("#item").outerwidth()));
```

Should do the trick